# Arithmetic operations by time-stamp in R

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, data.table, time-series

I have two data-frames (df1, df2) containing some measurements over roughly the same time period but different time stamps. df1 has hourly data, df2 has data that has 2-3 measurements per hour. I want to:

1. Compare the hourly average for df2 to the hourly value in df i.e. one value per hour from each data-frame
2. Create a new element in df2 (df2$hrly) which has a value equal to the hourly value from df1 for each time-stamp in df2 i.e. 2-3 values per hour (depending the no. of time-stamps in df2 for that hour)

`subset`, `filter` don't really work for this case - and I don't want to use loops. I'm considering using `strftime` and `aggregate` - is there a better way to do this? I'm learning about the `data.table` package - perhaps, there is a faster/more convenient method?

Here's what df1 and df2 look like:

```
> glimpse(df1)
Observations: 7,770
Variables: 7
$ lat      <dbl> 30.46198, 30.46198, 30.46198, 30.46198, 30.46198, 30....
$ lon      <dbl> -91.17922, -91.17922, -91.17922, -91.17922, -91.17922...
$ date_gmt <chr> "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01...
$ time_gmt <chr> "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00",...
$ dust     <dbl> 10.7, 8.0, 8.3, 11.1, 9.1, 10.5, 9.7, 13.5, 10.5, 10....
$ state    <chr> "Louisiana", "Louisiana", "Louisiana", "Louisiana", "...
$ tme      <dttm> 2016-01-01 06:00:00, 2016-01-01 07:00:00, 2016-01-01...
```

`df1$tme` is a `POSIxct` object (`tz = "GMT"`)

```
> glimpse(df2)
Observations: 5,000
Variables: 9
$ dp1        <dbl> 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.9...
$ dp2        <dbl> 1.51, 1.53, 1.55, 1.56, 1.56, 1.56, 1.56, 1.56, 1.5...
$ hz         <dbl> 54.13, 54.55, 54.91, 55.03, 54.98, 55.00, 55.13, 55...
$ rh         <dbl> 68.15, 68.56, 69.84, 68.32, 69.62, 71.14, 70.42, 70...
$ degc       <dbl> 82.88, 82.33, 82.26, 82.62, 82.20, 81.60, 82.05, 81...
$ cfm        <dbl> 3993, 3990, 3989, 3928, 3967, 4045, 4002, 3979, 403...
$ dust       <dbl> 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.0...
$ time_stamp <dttm> 2016-06-01 17:48:10, 2016-06-01 18:08:12, 2016-06-...
$ dur        <dbl> 0.0000000, 0.3338889, 0.6677778, 1.0013889, 1.33555...
```

`df2$time_stamp` is `POSIxct` object (`tz = "EST"`)

Comment: The `glimpse` is not very helpful in a question since others cannot copy-and-paste it into their sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't have test data, this is the best I can do. Hopefully it works.

I am assuming you want to compare the dust variable (only common variable in your dataframes). I am also assuming that comparing means that you just want to look at the delta.

**Steps:**

1. Make sure that your timezones are the same
2. Transform your time stamps to hourly data
3. Calculate the mean of your variable/s by hourly time
4. Merge based on the time stamp
5. Calculate a delta for your comparison

**Testdata:**

```
library(data.table)
df1<-data.table(tme=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00",tz="GMT"),by=3600, length.out = 100),dust=rnorm(100))
df2<-data.table(matrix(rnorm(1000*8),1000,8))
setnames(df2, c("dp1","dp2", "hz","rh","degc", "cfm", "dust","dur"))
df2[,time_stamp:=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00",tz="EST"),by=360, length.out = 1000)]

dplyr::glimpse(df1)
dplyr::glimpse(df2)
```

**Code:**

```
#first snippet
attr(df2$time_stamp,"tzone")<-"GMT" #make same timezone
df2[, tme:=lubridate::round_date(time_stamp, unit = "hours")] #make hourly timestamps
df3<-df2[, mean(dust), by=c("tme")] #group by tme I am assuming you want to compare the only common variable dust
setnames(df3, c("tme","dustmean"))
df_compare<-merge(df1, df3, by="tme", all=T) #this will include all observations from both data.tables
df_compare[,delta_dust:=dust-dustmean] #is that what you want as comparison?
plot(df_compare$delta_dust)
```

**Code2:**
For all variables (columns) with EST time and round_date instead.

```
#second snippet
attr(df1$tme,"tzone")<-"EST" #make same timezone
df2[, tme:=lubridate::round_date(time_stamp, unit="hours")] #make hourly timestamps
cols2mean<-colnames(df2)
cols2mean<-cols2mean[!(cols2mean %in% c("tme", "time_stamp"))]
df3<-df2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=c("tme"), .SDcols=cols2mean] #all variables except tme and time_stamp
df_compare<-merge(df1, df3, by="tme", all=T) #this will include all observations from both data.tables
df_compare[,delta_dust:=dust.x-dust.y] #one example
plot(df_compare$delta_dust)
```

Comment: In my script I use `format(df1$tme , tz = "EST", usetz = TRUE)` to make sure they are the same time and I use `round(df1$tme, units = "hours)` since seconds aren't relevant for this analysis.
While the mean dust value is good for part 1 of my question, it does not answer part 2 of the question. There're other columns (removed here) which are used to perform some calculations. 
I really ought to improve my understanding of data.table operations.

Comment: @Marwaha which columns do you need? All of them?

Comment: Basically, for each time stamp in df2, I want to use the rounded-off value of `time_stamp` and use that to find the corresponding value from df2 - something like `subset(df1, tme == round(df2$time_stamp[i], units = "hours") %>% select(dust)` where `i` corresponds to the current step in a loop `for(i in 1:nrow(df2))`

Comment: the two actual datasets would have columns very similar to `dust` - just more of them. For now, I need dp1, dp2, dust, cfm, degc and rh

Comment: @Marwaha the new code snippet should do the stuff you want. Have a try.

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I try to copy and run the code snippet. Is there a way to share all my code and the corresponding files here? Might be easier to see what's happening then.

Comment: @Marwaha I have added some test data now. I works with that. There were two problems: first of all your round statement does not work properly with data.table so I reverted back to the lubridate I had before. Second, I had an error in there as well (unbalanced bracket plus "=" where "%in%" was needed in the second example). Anyways, lesson learned: Test data is important and do not write code from the top of your head. Try again, if not you can send me some test data via dropbox, but I won't check it till much later.

Comment: Was occupied with a few other things - here's a dropbox link that contains the actual code snipper along with the relevant files. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/snp6t38xecbcwl8/AABMSG7Fr37ZCuL6lZi0Iamga?dl=0